# pinescript : Mismatched input end of line without line continuation

Tags: pine-script

Can you help me to relove it ?

I have verify indentation, testing lot of deferent code.
I have try to change version of pinescript.
Same error with :

```
if (rsi < 30)
  plotshape(series=high, shape=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `plot*()` functions inside an `if` block (or any local scope for that matter). `plot*()` functions have to be on global scope.

As a workaround, you can either use `label` or set the series with a ternary operator:

```
plotshape(series=rsi < 30 ? high : na, shape=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I don't have error now.
But this code don't plot my triangle Up or triangle Down on graphics I don't know why :

plotshape(series=(rsi < 30 and rsi[1] >= 30) and (rsi > 50 and rsi[1] <= 50) ? high : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)

And I can't remove "na" if I remove I have error.

Comment: `rsi` can’t be lower than 30 and higher than 50 at the same time, so the statement will always return false and won’t plot anything

Comment: Please note that in your case, since the `plotshape()` function receives a `bool` you should call the function without the ternary operator (since you can't really return `high` in this function): `plotshape(series=(rsi < 30 and rsi[1] >= 30) and (rsi > 50 and rsi[1] <= 50), style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar)`. Again - don't forget to fix the logic as mentioned in previous comment